# How to provide in git credentials during push command?

Tags: git

I am using windows powershell to create an automated script that will clone a repo, do some stuff to it, and then finally push it.

Here is my code so far:

```
git clone <github-domain>.com/org/repo

cd org/

echo "new content" >> newfile.txt

git add .

git commit -m "added new content"

git push origin master # here I receive a pop up asking me for my username and password
```

I'm wondering if its possible to pass in the username and password during the `push` command, since this should be fully automated.

Something like:

`git push origin master --username a --password b`

I tried looking online but all sources just pointed towards ssh and there was no "automated" way of doing this.

Comment: Set up your git config.  [Here's documentation for the password](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store), and the username can be configured: `git config user.name "name"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [git-credential-store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)

only for the first time, you need pass password
Follow Below steps:

```
git config credential.helper store
git push origin master
# supply username and Password for the 1st time
```

Now next time they don't ask for the username or password

Thanks!

Comment: I do not have access to this account. I can only run scripts on it but cannot remote into it to do this

Comment: normally the ideal way of doing this is to configure `ssh keys`, To run your script you should have ssh access to it. without that how could you run the script.